# update center of screen with current location

Tags: ios, swift, gps, center, region

I have successfully made an app that shows a blinking blue dot where the user currently is. However as of right now the center of the screen does not follow the blue dot as the user moves, so if the user moves the blue dot just exits the screen and the user would have to scroll to keep up with it. That isnt user friendly! I have the below code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var mapp = MKMapView.self

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {
            self.locationManager.delegate = self
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.map.showsUserLocation = true
        }
        else
        {
            print("Location services are not enabled")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.002, longitudeDelta: 0.002))
        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

My only thoughts are that I could get rid of the "stopUpdatingLocation() section and maybe then it would continuously update the region with the new center for every new location, however I am not sure if not having the stopUpdatingLocation is bad practice? Thanks for all advice!

Comment: You don't need any code to do this. You can just set the `userTrackingMode` property on your MapView and the map view will do it for you.

Comment: Wow thats very convenient. Is there a link somewhere that has all information about GPS methods?

Comment: There is a ton of documentation at http://developer.apple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [userTrackningMode](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1616208-usertrackingmode) which causes the map view to center the map on that location and begin tracking the user’s location. If the map is zoomed out, the map view automatically zooms in on the user’s location, effectively changing the current visible region.

To use it

```
mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated:true)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am assuming in my example I would need to do self.map.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)?

Comment: Yes, @skyleguy.

Comment: I have added the above code right under the line "self.map.showsUserLocation = true" and the dot still leaves the screen whenever I move around with the app up. is this not the correct place to add it?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? Otherwise try to place it under `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didChange mode: MKUserTrackingMode, animated: Bool)` method.

Comment: Does this function need to override another? Or can I just put "func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didChange mode: MKUserTrackingMode, animated: Bool){

Comment: using this method, if user traveling map does not update smoothly, is any solution for this?